# usage of Extract of method , Extract of Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

Hi I'm new to Flutter and I have question regarding Extract Method and Extract Widget in Android Studio.

When it comes to making code clean and reusable, what is the difference between Extract Method and Extract Widget? When do I know what to use? It seems they both work fine to me.